# Почему не подключаются стили для подпапки мультисайта на WP?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Настраиваю мультисайт на WordPress. Основной сайт встает нормально, доп. сайт должен быть в подпапке. HTML доп.сайта загружается, стили, js, картинки нет - в консоли 404 на все эти ресурсы.
На тестовом хостинге все работает нормально. На нужном мне сервере нужно прописывать конфиги для домена, в которых не разбираюсь.

Вот мой конфиг, взятый с аналогичного сайта с того же сервера, разрабатываемого по аналогичному ТЗ:

```
    server_name SITE.RU www.SITE.RU;
    charset off;
    index index.php index.html;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/SITE.RU/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/SITE.RU.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/SITE.RU.error.log notice;
    set $root_path /var/www/papka/data/www/SITE.RU;
    root $root_path;
    client_max_body_size 3M;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # wp permalinks
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
    }
    location @php {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@SITE.RU";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/papka.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
        # Compression settings
    #gzip                on;
    #gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    #gzip_min_length     150;
    #gzip_vary           on;
    #gzip_proxied        any;
    #gzip_comp_level     9;
    #gzip_buffers        16 8k;
    #gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

    
    # WordPress sitemap.xml 404 tweak
    #rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.xml$        "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2" last;
    #rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.xml\.gz$    "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2;zip=true" last;
    #rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.html$       "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2;html=true" last;
    #rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.html.gz$    "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2;html=true;zip=true" last;
    


    # Indexing settings
    # Setting indexing everything without restrictions
    #set $indexing "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";
    set $indexing       "all";
      
    # Set up indexing settings
    add_header          X-Robots-Tag $indexing; 

    server_name SITE.RU www.SITE.RU;
    ssi on;
    access_log off;
    listen 111.11.1.111:80;
}
server {
    server_name SITE.RU www.SITE.RU;
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/papka/SITE.RU_le1.crtca";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/papka/SITE.RU_le1.key";
    ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
    charset off;
    index index.php index.html;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/SITE.RU/*.conf;
    error_log /dev/null crit;
    set $root_path /var/www/papka/data/www/SITE.RU;
    root $root_path;
    client_max_body_size 3M;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # wp permalinks

        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
        
    }

    location @php {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@SITE.RU";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/papka.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        
                # proxy buffers - no 502 errors!
        proxy_buffer_size               128k;
        proxy_buffers                   4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size         256k;
 
        # fastcgi buffers - no 502 errors!
        fastcgi_buffering               on;
        fastcgi_buffer_size             16k;
        fastcgi_buffers                 16 16k;
    }
    
        
    gzip                on;
    gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_min_length     150;
    gzip_vary           on;
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_comp_level     9;
    gzip_buffers        16 8k;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

    set $cache_uri $request_uri;
    ssi on;
    access_log off;
    listen 111.11.1.111:443 ssl;
}
server {
    server_name www.SITE.RU;
    return 301 $scheme://SITE.RU$request_uri;
    
}
```

Вот мой .htaccess, но не думаю, что проблема в нем:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Пои чём тут .htaccess? nginx игнорирует эти файлы.

Comment: Вот правила nginx для WordPress мультисайта в подпапке: https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/#wordpress-multisite-subdirectory-rules. Используйте их.